PrimeFaces JS resources have no content type header since Jakarta migration of Spring Boot JSF app
I have started to migrate from Javax to Jakarta namespace in my application, I have replaced all Javax imports with Jakarta imports through out my code. I have following dependencies

spring boot 3
Primefaces 12.0.0 (from Jakarta namespace)
MyFaces 4.0.2

I have managed to run the application successfully but when xhtml file send from server (TOMCAT server 10), I observed that it failed to set the content type header to all the JS file response and hence my application fails to load in browser.
Following are some information about configurations,
FacesServlet registration in spring boot
 @Bean
    ServletRegistrationBean facesServletRegistration() {
        ServletRegistrationBean reg = new ServletRegistrationBean();
        reg.setServlet(new jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet());
        reg.addUrlMappings("*.html");
        reg.setName("faces");
        reg.setOrder(1);
        reg.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        return reg;
    }

faces-config.xml initial content
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<faces-config
    metadata-complete="false"
    xmlns:cdk="http://jboss.org/schema/richfaces/cdk/extensions"
    xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/faces-config_4_0.xsd"
    version="4.0">

    <application>
        <view-handler>com.warp.faces.facelets.CustomViewHandler</view-handler>
        <resource-handler>com.warp.app.CustomResourceHandler</resource-handler>

        <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
        
        <locale-config>
            <default-locale>en</default-locale>
            <supported-locale>de_DE</supported-locale>
            <supported-locale>en_DE</supported-locale>
        </locale-config>

        <resource-bundle>
            <base-name>com.warp.bundle.TextBundle</base-name>
            <var>text</var>
        </resource-bundle>
        <resource-bundle>
            <base-name>com.warp.bundle.MessageBundle</base-name>
            <var>messages</var>
        </resource-bundle>
        </application>

ServeltContextListener registration
@Component
public class Initializer implements ServletContextInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) {
        // MyFaces does not register itself without this:
        servletContext.setAttribute("org.apache.myfaces.DYNAMICALLY_ADDED_FACES_SERVLET", Boolean.TRUE);
        servletContext.addListener(org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener.class);
    }

}

What are the way I tried so far
I tried to set the content-type header while serving the files
public class CustomResourceHandler extends PrimeResourceHandler {

    private final ResourceHandler wrapped;

    public CustomResourceHandler(ResourceHandler wrapped) {
        super(wrapped);
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
    }

    @Override
    public ResourceHandler getWrapped() {
        return wrapped;
    }

    @Override
    public Resource createResource(String resourceName, String libraryName) {
        Resource resource = super.createResource(resourceName, libraryName);
        if (resource != null && resourceName.endsWith(".js")) {
            return new CustomResource(resource);
        }
        return resource;
    }

    private static class CustomResource extends Resource {

        private final Resource wrapped;

        public CustomResource(Resource wrapped) {
            this.wrapped = wrapped;
            setResourceName(wrapped.getResourceName());
            setLibraryName(wrapped.getLibraryName());
            setContentType("application/javascript");
        }

        @Override
        public void setContentType(String contentType) {
            wrapped.setContentType(contentType);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean userAgentNeedsUpdate(FacesContext facesContext) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public String getRequestPath() {
            return wrapped.getRequestPath();
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getResponseHeaders() {
            return wrapped.getResponseHeaders();
        }

        @Override
        public URL getURL() {
            return wrapped.getURL();
        }

        @Override
        public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
            return wrapped.getInputStream();
        }
    }
}

Tried to set MIME type
public class MimeMapper implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory> {
    @Override
    public void customize(ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory factory) {
        MimeMappings mappings = new MimeMappings(MimeMappings.DEFAULT);
        mappings.add("ecss", "text/css");
        mappings.add("css.html", "text/css");
        mappings.add("css", "text/css");
        mappings.add("js.html", "application/javascript");
        factory.setMimeMappings(mappings);
        Compression compression = new Compression();
        compression.setEnabled(true);
        factory.setMimeMappings(mappings);
        factory.setCompression(compression);
    }
}

Added ResourceResolver and configured it
public class MyResourceResolver implements ResourceResolver {

    @Override
    public Resource resolveResource(HttpServletRequest request, String requestPath, List<? extends Resource> locations, ResourceResolverChain chain) {
        Resource resource = chain.resolveResource(request, requestPath, locations);
        if (resource != null && requestPath.endsWith(".js")) {
            request.setAttribute("Content-Type", "application/javascript");
        }
        return resource;
    }

    @Override
    public String resolveUrlPath(String resourcePath, List<? extends Resource> locations, ResourceResolverChain chain) {
        return chain.resolveUrlPath(resourcePath, locations);
    }
}


@Configuration
    public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
                    .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/")
                    .setCachePeriod(3600)
                    .resourceChain(true)
                    .addResolver(new MyResourceResolver());
        }
    }

Added filter
@Component
public class MimeTypeFilter implements Filter {


    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (servletResponse.getContentType()==null) {
            servletResponse.setContentType("application/javascript");
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }
}

All above option not worked for me. Please see below screen shot of the errors in browser console

